# React.Js how to redirect on form submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mongoose

everyone.

So I have a an app, where the user can create posts, if you are the owner of this post, you can click on delete button which will show a modal and you can delete the post.

I can delete the post, but now I am trying to redirect the user back to the main page or any other page, however It doesn't work.

I tried using history.push, but it is not available, window.location.replace("/") doesn't work, and I even tried using this

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

and in the form submit

```
navigate("/");
```

This doesn't work at all, instead what happens is:

- The DELETE request gets send
- The post gets deleted from the database
- The page reloads and doesn't redirect the user
- The console throws fetch error

The user can see that the post is deleted only after he manualy switches pages, which I don'T want, I want the user to be automaticaly redirected once he pressed the Delete post button.

This is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.41",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

And this is my code for form submit and delete on the Post

```
const Post_page = () => {

  const auth = useContext(context_auth);
  
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpRequest();
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const userID = useParams().id;

  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [postID, setPostId] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();
  const [creator_name, setCreatorName] = useState();
  const [creationTime, setCreationTime] = useState('');

  const openModal = (event: any) =>  {
      setShowModal(true);
  }
  const closeModal = (event: any) =>  {
      setShowModal(false);
  }
  const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    try {
      const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${postID}`;
      await sendRequest(url, 'DELETE');
      window.location.replace("/");
      closeModal(event);

    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
    
   
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {

        const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${userID}`;
        const responseData = await sendRequest(url);

       console.log(responseData.post);
       const data = responseData.post;

       setTitle(data.title);
       setDescription(data.description);
       setPostId(data.id);
       const timeOfCreation = new Date(data.createdAt).toDateString();
       setCreationTime(timeOfCreation);
       setCreatorName(data.creator_name);

      } catch (err) { }}

      fetchPosts();
  }, [sendRequest]);


  return (
    <>
    {isLoading &&
      <h1>Loading ...</h1>
    }
    { !isLoading && showModal &&  auth.isLoggedIn &&   
      <Modal title='Delete post' show={showModal} onCancel={closeModal}>
        <>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} classname='modal_content_height_auto'>
            <p className='post_description'>Do you want to delete this post ?</p>
            <Button 
                classname='button_submit' 
                classname_enabled='button_submit_enabled' 
                classname_disabled='button_submit_disabled' 
                type='submit'
                label='Delete' 
      
              />
          </Form>
        </>
        

      </Modal>
    }

    { !isLoading &&
    
     <here is the post stuff, hidden as its not important>
      <Comments />
      </div>
    }
    </>
  )
}

export default Post_page
```

EDIT: Posting backend code for post DELETE

this is my route

```
route.delete('/:postID', deletePost)
```

and this is the deletePost handler

```
export const deletePost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const postID = req.params.postID;
    let post: any;

    try {
        post = await POST.findById(postID).populate('creator_id');
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err.message)
        const error = {
            message: "Couldn't delete POST !",
            code: 500
        };
    
        return next(error);
    }

    if(!post){
        const error = {
            message: "Post doesn't exist, so it could not be deleted !",
            code: 404
        };
    
        return next(error);
    }

    try{
       await post.remove();
       post.creator.posts.pull(post);
       await post.creator.save();
       
    }catch(err){
        const error = {
            message: "Couldn't delete POST from DATABASE!",
            code: 500
        };
    
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted !"});
}
```

EDIT: ADDED SCHEMA FOR POST AND USER
This is my Schema for Post which is also connected to User Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const post_Schema = new Schema({
        title: { type: String, required: true, },
        description: { type: String, required: true, },
        imageURL: { type: String },
        creator_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'  }, //relation bewtean post and user
        creator_name: { type: String, required: true, ref: 'User'  }, //relation bewtean post and user
    },
    { timestamps: true }
    );

export const POST: mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("Post", post_Schema);
```

and this is my User Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import mongooseUniqueValidator from "mongoose-unique-validator";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const validator = mongooseUniqueValidator;

const user_Schema = new Schema({
        username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3 },
        user_image: { type: String },
        posts: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Post'  }], //relation bewtean post and user

    },{ timestamps: true }
    );

user_Schema.plugin(validator);


export const USER: mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("User", user_Schema);
```

Comment: Using the `useNavigate` hook is the correct answer. Can you share how you were trying to use it, and be more specific about what isn't working, errors, etc?

Comment: I tried to use it this way, as I saw it somewhere on the internetz  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    try {
      const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${postID}`;
      await sendRequest(url, 'DELETE');
      closeModal(event);
      navigate('/');
    
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
   
  }

Comment: Are there any errors, in the console or network tab? If there aren't any thrown errors or rejected Promises the `navigate` function should be called. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see where it is failing for you? It seems the DELETE request or response handling is causing an error.

Comment: Well I know the error gets thrown inside the useEffect(), because thats where I am trying to get the post, the post gets deleted, the page reloads and useEffect() gets ingaged and its trying to get the post from database, but since the post no longer exists it throws an error and I know that when you redirect, all functions should stop.

Comment: The `fetchPosts` doesn't do anything in its `catch` block, are you *sure* this is where the error is being logged?

Comment: I made a special script for fetch API, the errors get logged from there. its just fetch function with parameters, so i could write less code

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your mongo Schema for the post ? Maybe you are trying to access a parameter that doesn't exist ? Which may give you an errror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you posted, the reason you don't redirect upon post deletion is because the backend prevents it from happening.

1. to redirect the user after he has deleted the post, if you are using **React-router-dom version 6**, you need to use **useNavigate()**, because useHistory and  have been replaced by useNavigate(), so this is how you would redirect the user if he deletes something.

```
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       try {
           const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${postID}`;
           await sendRequest(url, 'DELETE');
           closeModal(event);
           navigate(`/`);
           } catch (err: any) {}
    }
```

2. The reason your post doesn'T redirect is because, when you send the DELETE request the backend sends back an error, but before the error happens the Post gets deleted from the database, and its happening in the second try..catch block. The error happens here ->

```
    post.creator.posts.pull(post);  //THIS IS WERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
```

The error happens because you are searching for creator in the **Post Schema**, but Post Schema doesn't have **creator** so it panics and throws an error, instead it has **creator_id** and **creator_name**, so you should replace it like this, if you are searching for user by ID

```
   post.creator_id.posts.pull(post);
```

So your code on the backend should look like this (Its totaly same expect the        **post.creator_id.posts.pull(post)**

```
export const deletePost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const postID = req.params.postID;
    let post: any;

    try {
        post = await POST.findById(postID).populate('creator_id');
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err.message)
        const error = {
            message: "Couldn't delete POST !",
            code: 500
        };
        return next(error);
    }

    if(!post){
        const error = {
            message: "Post doesn't exist, so it could not be deleted !",
            code: 404
        };
        return next(error);
    }
    try{
       await post.remove();
       post.creator_id.posts.pull(post);
       await post.creator_id.save();
       
    }catch(err){
        const error = {
            message: "Couldn't delete POST from DATABASE!",
            code: 500
        };
    
        return next(error);
    }
    res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted !"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to useNavigate only, since you are using react router v6

```
const Post_page = () => {

  const auth = useContext(context_auth);
  const navigate=useNavigate();
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpRequest();
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const userID = useParams().id;

  const [title, setTitle] = useState();
  const [postID, setPostId] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();
  const [creator_name, setCreatorName] = useState();
  const [creationTime, setCreationTime] = useState('');

  const openModal = () =>  {
      setShowModal(true);
  }
  const closeModal = () =>  {
      setShowModal(false);
  }
  const onSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    try {
      const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${postID}`;
      await sendRequest(url, 'DELETE');
      //window.location.replace("/");
      navigate("/");
      closeModal();

    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
    
   
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {

        const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/${userID}`;
        const responseData = await sendRequest(url);

       console.log(responseData.post);
       const data = responseData.post;

       setTitle(data.title);
       setDescription(data.description);
       setPostId(data.id);
       const timeOfCreation = new Date(data.createdAt).toDateString();
       setCreationTime(timeOfCreation);
       setCreatorName(data.creator_name);

      } catch (err) { }}

      fetchPosts();
  }, [sendRequest]);


  return (
    <>
    {isLoading &&
      <h1>Loading ...</h1>
    }
    { !isLoading && showModal &&  auth.isLoggedIn &&   
      <Modal title='Delete post' show={showModal} onCancel={closeModal}>
        <>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} classname='modal_content_height_auto'>
            <p className='post_description'>Do you want to delete this post ?</p>
            <Button 
                classname='button_submit' 
                classname_enabled='button_submit_enabled' 
                classname_disabled='button_submit_disabled' 
                type='submit'
                label='Delete' 
      
              />
          </Form>
        </>
        

      </Modal>
    }

    { !isLoading &&
    
     <here is the post stuff, hidden as its not important>
      <Comments />
      </div>
    }
    </>
  )
}

export default Post_page
```

Comment: This is excatly how I used it, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the server side code. Probably after delete some response issue is happening.

Comment: This is my deletePost, it works, the post gets deleted from database, the error is not happening here, but in the frontend, I am sorry for wrong formating, I do not know how to style it in comments

Comment: `export const deletePost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {const postID = req.params.postID;  let post: any;try { post = await POST.findById(postID).populate('creator_id'); } catch (err: any) {console.log(err.message)const error = {message: "Couldn't delete POST !", code: 500 };return next(error); } if(!post){const error = {message: "Post doesn't exist, so it could not be deleted !", code: 404 };

Comment: return next(error);}try{ awaitpost.remove();post.creator.posts.pull(post); await post.creator.save();}catch(err){const error = { message: "Couldn't delete POST from DATABASE!",code: 500 };returnnext(error);}res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted !"});}`

Comment: Can you please update the question with this code. Another option to test would be to use Postman for testing Backend API

Comment: I was using Postman, before adding React.Js, deleting posts works on both, its just that redirecting user when the post gets deleted doesn't work

Comment: ok..did you try checking the network tab(as mentioned in 1 comment). check the response.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a fetch error from the delete request, that means neither of `window.location.replace` or `closeModal` functions are getting invoked because catch block is executed right after the error. Make sure that you are getting the right response from that API call.

Comment: The fetch and closeModal get executed, but the user is not redirected, I know the error gets thrown inside the of useEffect(), where I am trying to get the post, but since the post is deleted in the database, it throws an error. I can't figure out how to stop it from executing

Comment: Why would the useEffect gets executed after you delete the post since the component does not get mounted again or sendRequest function does not change? Just a bit confused there :)

Comment: I am not really sure, thats what I was told what happens. But I think it has to do something with changing data in the useState.

Comment: You can console.log something right after 'await sendRequest' and check whether that something is showing up in your console. If not, rest of the try block is not getting executed.

Comment: @mitas1c The `onSubmit` doesn't enqueue any state updates, so it is not triggering any rerenders. I think you have been misinformed. Something isn't adding up here.